# calling wcf /web service from php/ruby

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, wcf, web-services

For my sins, I am in charge of developing a service for providing data to both our internal systems running .net apps as well as external systems running php.  For the sake of future proofing, I want to ensure it is callable from ruby as well.

My service will perform authentication and look up account details from a central user repository.  So go to our php web front end, enter username/password and the php app calls my thing.  Internally, it will be wcf over local tcp/ip, externally, webservice, possibly ws-security.

Obviously, we want to ensure this thing is only called by trusted callers.  My initial inclination is to insist on some client certificate mechanism, but as I am a complete n00b outside of the .net world, I need some advice.

Do current php/ruby implementations of web service calls support caller client certs?  I'm going to go ahead and assume the php/ruby callers run on some standard, modern version of linux.  What are the pitfalls to watch out for?  The last thing I want is to build this awesome thing, have our .net callers work fine and then need to rebuild it/kludge something together to get it working for our php callers.

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you use another authentication mechanism (API authorization) to accessing your service? You can generate a private key for every client and let them use your services providing the correct key over https.

Look http://oauth.net/